# How do I create a team in ESXi Server?

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-esxi, virtualhost, vmware-workstation

I have three VMware Workstation 7.03 VMs collected in one team that works great on Workstation 7.03.  I would like to convert/transfer the team to ESXi (I have a working host) but the VMware Client Converter (runs on Windows) will not convert the team (*.vmtm file) to ESXi.

Is this doable?  How?  Limitations?

Comment: I believe that http://communities.vmware.com/thread/205259 (third entry from top) suggests that ESXi can host teams.  But there is little detail there or any other information I can find that supports this one hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff is somewhat right in his comment about vApps. A vApp is a similar logical container for virtual machines. There are, however, a couple caveats/notes:

1. vApps are a function of VirtualCenter. You cannot create a vApp without a vCenter server.
2. vApps are much more feature rich than teams. Networking within a vApp is a good example.

So, unless you are willing to fork the cash out for vCenter, you will have to convert them as mrdenny stated, and lose the team functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to pull them from the team, and make them three standalone VMs under VMware Workstation.  If when you created them you created then using one of the VMware formats that ESXi understands then you can just copy the files up to the server, and attach the VM to the ESXi box and start the VM.  No conversation is needed.  If not, then you'll need to convert.  ESXi doesn't have teams like VMware Workstation does, so the converter probably doesn't know what to do with the team.

Comment: vSphere uses "vApps" which are largely equivalent to "Teams" in workstation.  I've not tried to export a Team from Workstation to see what is possible - so you may have to go the way MrDenny suggested.  Export them separately from Workstation, import into ESXi and then create your vApp in ESXi.